# Hide position:fixed text on background-attachment:fixed, position:relative; behind text scrolling below

Tags: html, css

When I scrolling the fixed text on the fixed background does not go under the body or p tags but rather scrolls on top. How do I get the fixed text to go underneath the body with the p elements What's the trick to setting the z-index to getting this working?
Codepen: https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/MBmaoj

```css
.parallax-bg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 90vh;
  min-height: 420px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax-text {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #13284a;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1200/700')">
    <div class="parallax parallax-text">"Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"</div>
  </div>
</section>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: there is no z-index specified in your code

Comment: It is also not very clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @TemaniAfif Apologies for the poor wording. I am trying to get the text that is on top of the background image to hide underneath the body of text that scrolls on top of it

Comment: As far as I can tell, all your text is above the background

Comment: so you want the p on top of the section?

Comment: @Huangism currently the 'Heading One' Text goes on top of the 'lorem ipsum' body below the background image on scroll. I am trying to get the 'Heading One' text to hide underneath the body

Comment: @Pete Yes that's correct

Comment: so position both the p and the section and make the z-index for the p higher - z-index only works on positioned siblings

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap all the p tags in a div and give it a z-index property with the below css

```
.pwrap {position: relative; z-index: 100; background: #ffffff;}
```

[Codelink](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrmbyd)

Comment: I tried that but there is still a gap that does not hide underneath the pwrap at the top...was thinking there was possibly a different approach

Comment: Set margin top to 0 for the `p`s

Comment: Then you might need to add a negative margin-top to pwrap to cover up the tiny gap created by something unknown to me. Like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBmgVb

Answer (score 0):

your

tags don't have any position,
and they don't have any background color,
to avoid appearing text between

tags, you'd better add some wrapper,
and it's not necessary add z-index in this case
please try:

```
    <section>
  <div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1200/700')">
    <div class="parallax parallax-text">"Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"</div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
.parallax-bg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 90vh;
  min-height: 420px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax-text {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #13284a;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9h1p6qx/1/

Comment: While you are on the right track, you should try your own solution first